# variable scope inside of d3 reusable API

Tags: javascript, namespaces, d3.js, closures, scope

I am trying to create a reusable data manager API for a reusable chart based on the book "Developing a d3.js Edge". 
you can find the code I am inspiring from in this [Github repository](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/Developing-a-D3.js-Edge/blob/master/code/chapter-06-12/08.01.drawRoutes/javascripts/transport.js).

So the data manager API goes like this:

```
 kdd.dataManager = function module(){

var exports = {}, 
    dispatch = d3.dispatch('dataReady', 'dataLoading'), 
    data; 

exports.loadJsonData = function(_uri, _callback){
    d3.json(_uri, function(_err, _data){
        _callback(_data);
    });
};

exports.loadCsvData = function(_file, _cleaningFunc){

    if(!_cleaningFunc) _cleaningFunc = function(d){
        return d;
    };

    var loadCsv = d3.csv(_file); 

    loadCsv.on('progress', function(){
        dispatch.dataLoading(d3.event.loaded); 
    }); 

    loadCsv.get(function(_err, _response){

        _response.forEach(function(d){
            _cleaningFunc(d);
        }); 

        // assign the data response to our data variable 
        data = _response;
        dispatch.dataReady(_response); 
    }); 
}; 

//access the data 
exports.getCleanedData = function(){
    return data; 
}; 


d3.rebind(exports, dispatch, 'on'); 
return exports; 
};
```

and the problem is that when I use the getCleanedData() method I get "undefined", and I only get the right data when I console.log the data variable inside exports.loadCsv.get().

```
    var newDataManager = kdd.dataManager(); 

var file= "data/sp500.csv"; 

newDataManager.loadCsvData(file); 
console.log(newDataManager.getCleanedData());
```

I can actually pass a callback function to the get function that would apply some logic when the data is loaded. But normally considering the variable scope within the name space the data variable should be accessible from outside the loadCsv.get method.

Could you please check what's wrong! 
Thanks & regards
Mohamed Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the data before it has had a chance to load.

```
newDataManager.loadCsvData(file);
```

Initiates a request to asynchronously load your data. Once that request is initiated (but before there has been time download), the next line of code executes:

```
console.log(newDataManager.getCleanedData());
```

Which is looking for data that doesn't exist yet.

If you'd like to access the cleanedData outside of the loadCsvData callback, you can listen for the `dataReady` event:

```
newDataManager.on('dataReady', function(data) {
  console.log(newDataManager.getCleanedData()); });
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but how can I wrap that within the API function getCleanedData(), I mean I don't want the user of the API to do that

Comment: I tried this exports.getCleanedData = function(){
  this.on('dataReady', function(data){
   return data;
  });
 }; but it's not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; who are the users of the API that you have in mind? I don't know how you would hide the asynchronous nature of loading remote data from them.

Comment: well good point! I'll just go with your recommendation, thanks for your help!